# Is it illegal to explain someone else's research paper on my website?

Tags: publications, citations, legal-issues

Can I explain someone else's research paper on my website if I am properly citing the paper author with a link from where I got access to that paper? The website takes no credit for the paper but only explains it in simple words.

Comment: Do you actually mean illegal?

Comment: This is widely done in the machine learning community.  There are many blogs and videos on hot influential algorithms or papers.

Comment: If you do not copy text verbatim (plagiarism), but explain or summarize with your own word, it is perfectly fine and this is what reviews do, too. For figures, you should ask permission from the publisher (it is generally free), but you can use those, too.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't quote too extensively from the paper, but do formally quote as needed, you should be fine.

Giving credit avoids plagiarism. Avoiding excessive quoting avoids possible copyright infringement.

But cite the "paper" itself, not just the "paper author".

I've assumed that you have proper access to the paper.

Comment: @Ninad Kale: For what it's worth, I've seen several nontrivial discussions of mathematics papers in the Stack Exchange groups *Mathematics Stack Exchange* and *History of Science and Mathematics* and *MathOverflow*, and in fact I've done this myself a few times, such as [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/214470/15780) and [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/162605/15780).